# difference between comments with 2 dashes vs 3 in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, comments

What is the difference between comments using 3 instead of 2 dashes?

Example `<!--comment here-->` vs `<!---comment here--->`
Also do people find it more readable if there's a space between the dashes and the text e.g.
`<!-- comment here -->`

Comment: Oh really? Notepadd++ has different syntax highlighting for the two.

Comment: @Tom - Good call on the edit!

Comment: @Leigh I almost rushed with a wrong answer to what seemed a trivial question myself. Seems you're the rare kind of person to carefully read the tags :)

Comment: @Tom - Not always ;) But being a CF developer it is a familiar question. (When first learning CF, I found out the hard way there really *is* difference. Thinking of my frustration at the time still makes me laugh :)

Comment: @Leigh haha, I don't know CF any better than I know Chinese but it's hard not to agree. With 90% languages out there resembling either C or XML, it is frustrating to see a syntax so similar in appearance, yet so different in meaning. What did you do? Embed implementation details in a publicly available html?

Comment: @Tom - Yeah, that is what makes switching back and forth between languages such fun ;-) Fortunately, my rookie mistake was not that bad. Just spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to figure out why a page would not compile. Only to have a senior developer point out (in two seconds) I was using the wrong type of comment... of all things. Duh! ;-)

Comment: @Leigh sounds familiar. My company's developing its own programming language and I've been using using its early versions for a while now. There's even more thrill to this. I've spent a couple of evenings wondering whether an error was my own mistake, or a bug somewhere on the way from preprocessor to bytecode.

Comment: @Tom - Lol, talk about a mind scrambler. A couple weeks of that could give you quite a complex ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12279/discussion-between-tom-and-leigh)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Two dashes signify an html comment. Content within html comments *are* included in the output of CF pages ie viewable in the html source.

Three dashes signify a ColdFusion comment. Anything enclosed within the comments is ignored by the ColdFusion compiler, and is *not* included in the html output.

Comment: In fairness to the others who responded, their answers are correct for `html`. As @Tom said, they probably just overlooked the `coldfusion` tag.